# Visualforce should display functionality for multiselect lookup Contact and filter it by given Account

Tags: visualforce, lookup

I've got the following requirement (firstable trying to explain it through the screenshot below):

[image]

I am testing, trying first.

1. The input field Account should be autocompleted when writting a part of an Account string there. This works
2. The Contacts search box should filter the contacts to the ones which belong to the given Account in 1) --> this is not working
3. When you are typing the name of a Contact, it also should be autocompleted --> this works
4. After entering the name of the contact and pressing the button "Add contact", the given contact should be added automatically to the textarea --> this is not woking
5. After pressing the button "Add contact" the search box should be displayed as empty --> not yet implemented
6. If you want to add more contacts, you just follow steps 3 to 4. Having done this, you should be able to see this in the textarea: Contact1; Contact2; etc. For example: Roger Moore; Betty Davis (if you added two contacts with those names) --> this is not working either

   Attendees
                         
                         
                             
                                 
                                    Account
                                    
                                 
                                 
                                    Contacts

This is part of my Apex controller code:

```
public class MyController {
    public List<String> listOfAccounts {get; set;}
    public List<String> listOfContacts {get; set;}

    public String mycontact{get;set;}
    public string lookUp{get;set;}
    public list<Contact> contactList{get;set;}
    Id accountId;
    public boolean bool{get;set;}
    public set<id> contactids{get;set;}

    //Constructor
    public MyController() {
        listOfAccounts = new List<String>();
        for(Account acc: [SELECT id, Name From Account])
            listOfAccounts.add(acc.name);

        listOfContacts = new List<String>();
        for(Contact contact: [SELECT id, Name, FirstName, LastName, AccountId From Contact where AccountId =: accountId ])
            listOfContacts.add(contact.name);
    }

    public boolean add_contact(){
        list<Contact> selectedContacts = new list<Contact>();
        lookUp = '';
        for(Contact conObj  : selectedContacts){
            if(conObj != null){
                system.debug('conObj'+conObj);
                selectedContacts.add(conObj);
                lookUp += conObj.name + ' ;' ;
                system.debug('lookUp::'+lookUp);
                contactids.add(conObj.id);
            }
        }

        return bool = true;
    }

    private Account getAccount(String acc_name){
        Account account = new Account();
        list<Account> accountList = [Select id, Name From Account Where Name = : acc_name];
        if (accountList != null && accountList.size()>0){
            account = accountList[0];
        }

        return account;
   }  

   private Contact getContact(String con_fname, String con_lname){
       Contact con = new Contact();
       list<Contact> contactList = [Select id, Name, FirstName, LastName, AccountId From Contact Where FirstName =: con_fname and LastName =: con_lname and AccountId =: accountId ];
       if (contactList != null && contactList.size()>0){
           con = contactList[0];
       }

       return con;
    }  
}
```

Would someone be kind to guide me, what I am missing in my codes? what would you correct in order to let this work out?. I would appreciate your answers.

Comment: You can put it smaller separate questions and try to achieve one by one. it seems you have given entire requirements of your project and asking us the complete

Comment: @Santanu: I can not believe there are some here posting critics instead of help. I am not here to let others solve my tasks, I am here to look at tips. If you believe I am here to let others to solve my task, be free to look at other threads instead of criticising. I would like to delete this thread, because I am pretty disappointed, I made efforts to make my thread understandable and not a topic for disliking and destructable critics like yours, so unrespectable!!!